# Should I run my condensate pump after pouring bleach water into it for cleaning?

Tags: air-conditioning

After I add the 50-50 mix of bleach water to the condensate pump to clear out the algae, do I add water to the pump? On top of the condensate pump it says "do not run dry" so I was wondering do I need to add water after I run the 50-50 mix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condensate pump should have a float switch in it so that it automatically comes on when there is water in it, and turns off when it's empty.

It is also possible to run the pump by pressing the test button (if it has one) or shorting the terminals on the float switch (if exposed) or in numerous other manners. Normally, you would not do this. However, if you do for whatever reason, then it is in these circumstances that you do not want to run the pump dry.

In your case, I would let the chlorinated water sit for up to 30 minutes, then pour in as much water as needed to completely flush the chlorine out of the well, pump and discharge line. Otherwise, if the pump has rubber seals the chlorine may damage them.

Comment: How much mix(bleach/water) should I pour...2 cups,4 or 6 cups?

Comment: That's a completely different question.

Comment: Do i run the air while i have the wet vac doing the suctioning?

Comment: You don't use a vacuum to clean a condensate pump. I think you have a problem with your overall procedure. Please post a new question with your intended goal (clean condensate pump and drain line) and your intended procedure. Then we can double check your thoughts.